# WebJob to read from and write to the same Azure blob

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-queues

I am trying to process images uploaded to azure using webjob. I have 2 containers `image` and `thumbs`.

Currently, I am reading from `image` container, creating a thumbnail and writing it to `thumbs` container using the following code, which works great.

```
public static void GenerateThumbnail([QueueTrigger("addthumb")] ImageDTO blobInfo,
                [Blob("images/{Name}", FileAccess.Read)] Stream input, [Blob("thumbs/{Name}")] CloudBlockBlob outputBlob)
    {
        using (Stream output = outputBlob.OpenWrite())
        {
            ConvertImageToThumbnail(input, output, blobInfo.Name);
            outputBlob.Properties.ContentType = GetMimeType(blobInfo.Name);
        }
    }
```

Now, I would also like to resize the main image from `image` container (if it's too big), compress it and replace the original with it.

Is there a way to read from and write to the same blob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can read/write to the same blob. For example you could change your `input` binding to bind to `CloudBlockBlob` using `FileAccess.ReadWrite`:

```
public static void GenerateThumbnail(
    [QueueTrigger("addthumb")] ImageDTO blobInfo,
    [Blob("images/{Name}", FileAccess.ReadWrite)] CloudBlockBlob input,
    [Blob("thumbs/{Name}")] CloudBlockBlob output)
{
    // Process the image  
}
```

You can then access the `OpenRead/OpenWrite` stream methods on that blob to read the image blob and process/modify it as needed.

Comment: Great, I'll try it soon!

Comment: Looking at your example, I presume I don't need to use queue at all? Can I trigger a webjob function when a new blob is added to a container?

Comment: I just updated the example :) Technically you don't need the queue, but use of a queue is the recommended pattern. `BlobTrigger` can trigger automatically, but there can be latencies as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-blobs-how-to/).

Comment: Can I do multiple binding to the same blob as well? for example, `[Blob("images/{Name}", FileAccess.Read)] Stream input,
    [Blob("images/{Name}")] CloudBlockBlob output` ?